# Divide a string into alphabets and digits

Tags: c++, string

So i want to make the int main like this. User can input the word as many time as they want (while(true)). Now the user can also write "alphabet+one number" or "alphabet+two numbers". For example, they insert the word "add 5", then i need to divide that word, going to the if(input=="add"), and make the number '5' go inside the function add(5). But for the update function, user can input two numbers. For example, they insert the word "update 1 2", meaning they want to update index 1 and change the value into 2. All of the add and update function works well, I used doubly linked list btw. But the problem is the int main part. It won't read the user input and I kept on getting error "string subscript out of range". Any idea? Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
    int main() 
    {
        int count = 0;
        string input, tempalpha;
        int tempnumber1,tempnumber2;
        while(true)
        {
            cin>>input;
            if(input=="exit")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0;i < input.size();i++)
                {
                    if (isalpha(input[i]))
                    {
                        tempalpha[i] = input[i];
                    }
                    else if (isdigit(input[i]))
                    {
                        tempnumber1 = input[i];
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (i != input.size() - 1 && count == 1)
                    {
                        tempnumber2 = input[i];
                    }
                }
                
                if (tempalpha == "add")
                {
                    add(tempnumber1);
                }
                else if (tempalpha == "update")
                {
                    //tempnumber1 is the index, tempnumber2 is the new value
                    update(tempnumber1,tempnumber2);
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: At no point do you allocate space for the characters in tempalpha.

Comment: `tempalpha += input[i];` would add the character to the end of the string.

Comment: `cin>>input;` reads up to the next white space. You could try something like: `cin>>input; if (input == "update") {int a, b; cin >> a >> b;}`

Comment: *and I kept on getting error "string subscript out of range.  Any idea?"* -- Let's hear what you believe this error message means.  It sounds very clear as to the issue.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?